# Why is not adblocking built into Firefox?

Tags: firefox, advertisements

Why is not very aggressive adblocking built directly into Firefox?

What kind of user really wants ads? For the life of me I can't figure out why this isn't a killer feature that would separate Firefox from other browsers and put it into a league of its own -- that goes for all browsers that would dare implement this as a standard feature.

Yes, I'm fully aware you can easily download and install it, but it should be built in. It is an essential feature of browsing that dramatically improves the end user experience of the software.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be posed directly to Firefox Developers at https://discourse.mozilla.org/search?q=why%20is%20ad%20blocking%20not%20built%20in%3F

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What kind of user really wants ads?

Advertising revenue models provide users services that are free to the end user; for example, this service you're posting on right now.

A great number of users in reality do take advantage of this model; even with its "you are the product"-type disadvantages.

Having a major browser outright declare war on advertising would likely induce businesses to actively block it, drive browser share to other more business-friendly browsers, and it would threaten Mozilla's core mission overall.

Thanks to the open source license that Firefox is released under, there is nothing stopping someone from forking Mozilla's code and making such a browser, though (you just can't call it Firefox or imply that Mozilla endorses it) and one may very well be out there.